# Part::wrsym Symbol Protected Error with ParallelMap

Tags: parallelization

Here's my minimal example:

```
xlist = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y1 = ConstantArray[{}, 4];
y2 = ConstantArray[{}, 4];
SetSharedVariable[y1, y2];
f[z_] := Block[{},
   {y1[[Position[xlist, z][[1, 1]]]], 
      y2[[Position[xlist, z][[1, 1]]]]} = 
     Extract[NMaximize[-(q - z)^2 + 2*z, q], {{1}, {2, 1, 2}}];
   ];
ParallelMap[f, xlist];
y1
y2
```

The `f[z]` function works fine on its own, but when I try to parallelize, I get the error `Part::wrsym : Symbol y1 is Protected` (and likewise for y2), even though I've used `SetSharedVariable`.  Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know exactly why it did not work but I found a way to circumvent it. The following seems to produce the desired result:

```
xlist = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y1 = ConstantArray[{}, 4];
y2 = ConstantArray[{}, 4];
SetSharedVariable[y1,y2];
f[z_] := Block[{bla, i},
   bla = Extract[NMaximize[-(q - z)^2 + 2*z, q], {{1}, {2, 1, 2}}];
   i = Position[xlist, z][[1, 1]];
   y1[[i]] = bla[[1]];
   y2[[i]] = bla[[2]];
   ];
ParallelMap[f, xlist];
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work well, although I was hoping to avoid defining an additional variable, `bla` in this case, because my `xlist` is going to be much, much larger and I thought doing so my offer a slight speed advantage (not sure if that's actually true).  In any case, I would like to know why the error in the original example arises, if only to deepen my understanding of how parallel computing works in Mathematica.